# Как сделать, чтобы при создании разметки по умолчанию создавался LinearLayout вместо RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio

Как сделать, чтобы при создании разметки по умолчанию создавался `LinearLayout` вместо `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: что такое `LL`, `RL`?

Comment: @metalurgus Relative и Linear

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы это было понятно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645161/how-to-change-default-template-layout-files-in-android-studio тут есть ответ.

Измени шаблон по умолчанию в файле по пути:

...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities

Дальше, смотря какой шаблон нужно изменить. Например, для EmptyActivity меняй файл по пути:

...\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\common\root\res\layout\simple.xml.ftl

Там можешь изменить шаблон, как тебе угодно, в том числе изменить корневой элемент на LinearLayout.

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!